# How to call a D3 script as a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to call a D3 script as a function?  Specifically to pass a data selector?

I have a simple donut chart that I use to display data for a month.  I'd like to be able to recall that same D3 graphic and pass it different data for each month of the year, based on an `onClick` event. So that the chart would be redrawn in the same space.

I've seen other charts that have a [radio selection](https://bl.ocks.org/tezzutezzu/c2653d42ffb4ecc01ffe2d6c97b2ee5e) that is triggered by `onchange` that runs a section of the D3 script again to redraw the graphic.  But can I not just setup my D3 script as a function, and call it whenever I want to display different data?

I have also seen a [chart here](http://embed.plnkr.co/gE1xQu/) that calls the D3 function using `(window.d3)`, but it does not seem like the function definition of `(function(d3){...}` will allow for any variables to be passed. Or maybe I don't understand exactly how that is executing.

What is the easiest way to accomplish a reactive chart based on a click outside the svg?

Comment: When you load d3 as a library, d3 becomes a global object available to you so you can do `d3.select...` etc from anywhere. From the radio button perspective in the callback of the onchange event, could you not just do `d3.select('element').doSomething()`?

Comment: @aug I'm not really sure to be honest.  I can't find anyone that is writing d3 examples called as functions.  I'm wondering if part of the issue isn't also variable scope?

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the d3 website but it looks like you accepted the below answer. I hope you actually understand if that helps answer your question but the idea is that when you detect a change event, you can call d3 from anywhere since d3 is added on the window object as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar job where I had links and I could select one of the links to select the appropriate JSON to use for the plot. Below is the HTML snippet of interest -

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a class="m" value="2014-02-19" href="#">2014-02-19</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2014-02-20" href="#">2014-02-20</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2014-02-21" href="#">2014-02-21</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2014-02-22" href="#">2014-02-22</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2014-02-23" href="#">2014-02-23</a></li>
                </ul>
...
```

This is the Javascript snippet doing the selection -

```
        //On click, update with new data            
        d3.selectAll(".m")
            .on("click", function() {
                var date = this.getAttribute("value");

                var str;
                if(date == "2014-02-19"){
                    str = "19.json";
                }else if(date == "2014-02-20"){
                    str = "20.json";
                }else if(date == "2014-02-21"){
                    str = "21.json";
                }else if(date == "2014-02-22"){
                    str = "22.json";
                }else{
                    str = "23.json";
                }

                d3.json(str,function(json){

                    dataset = json;
                    stack(dataset);
                    ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like a great way to do this.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have your full code posted anywhere by chance?  I've got the selection working, but I can't get it to redraw the graphic.  I'm not using stack anywhere, so I guess I'm not sure what to call there.

Comment: I do not have it yet. But will do so.

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/h7zz0a61/ . You will not be able to see the plot as I could not stuff the data.